# Location for mapping node in percentage

Tags: texturing

friends.

Is there any way to change the location of a gradient texture with "mapping node" using distance in percentage instead of distance in meters?
For example, I need the gradient texture to be always in the center of the object (x and y coordinates). Even when the array modifier is applied to the object. And this material is used by several objects of different sizes.

Something like on this picture:

NOW
[image: current texture example]

MUST BE
[image]

Additional info:

- Eevee
- NOT as a postprocessing effect.

Comment: Have you tried the Generated coordinates ?

Comment: yes :) I tried many other things

Comment: Maybe if you used geometry nodes instead of an array modifier, and then you could use a python driver to control the material…

Comment: There are flaws with my method, I'll try again.

Answer (score 0):

I find that this is possible given certain constraints.

If you are not using the *Array Modifier* to scale the object.

AND

If your object's coordinates do not intersect each other over the axis you're wanting to use.

For example, in my test scene I have an array of 5 cubes that do not share any space on any axis of the coordinate grid.

[image]

This way we can make it repeat without overwriting a portion of the previous object.  You only need to clear the object on the axis you want to use for the shader.

I found a pretty robust way to do this is to use an *Object Offset* for the *Array Modifier*.

[image]

We can start with two *Texture Coordinate* nodes to reference both the Cube and the Empty, and *Subtract* their *Object Coordinates*.  We then need to *Vector Math* -> *Divide* this result by 2 in theory, but in practice it's better to divide by some value slightly larger than 2. I used 2.0001 which is truncated to 2.000 in the UI, but it's important to know because it solves some floating point precision stuff that can pop up.

[image]

And it generates this intense white color, which is at first glance not very useful to us, but now we can use either the *Vector Math* -> *Modulo* OR *Wrap* node to make the Cube's *Generated Coordinates* repeat over the distance between the Cube and the Empty on each axis.  Maybe someone with an advanced math degree can take this even further.

[image]

[image]

SO... to answer the actual question, finally, it's all of that, and then your subtract operation.

[image]

Comment: Different sizes is a different beast.